# aspxPivotGrid ShowTotalsForSingleValues

Tags: asp.net, grid, devexpress

The aspxPivotGrid has an OptionsView property called "ShowTotalsForSingleValues". I want this setting on, but the problem is it then will show single values totals for all fields in the column area.

Is there a way to display single value totals for one field?

Answer (score 2):

You would need to use a custom total (http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/CustomDocument7310) to do this by default the  automatic totals will do as you say (give a total for each data field). I hope this helps.